# TypeError: Cannot read property 'PROVIDER_ID' of undefined

Tags: angular, package.json

i use firebase 3.9.0, firebaseui 2.4.1, firebaseui-angular 0.4.5 and angular 4.
When i click in my login page where firebase ui is used then throw TypeError: Cannot read property 'PROVIDER_ID' of undefined.
Snippet of my package.json is

```
"dependencies": {
        "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
        "@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
        "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
        "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
        "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
        "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
        "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
        "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
        "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
        "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
        "angular-font-awesome": "^2.3.7",
        "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc0",
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "firebase": "^3.9.0",
        "firebaseui": "^2.4.1",
        "firebaseui-angular": "^0.4.5",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "install": "^0.10.1",
        "ng2-daterangepicker": "^2.0.10",
        "ngx-carousel": "^1.2.5",
        "ngx-popover": "0.0.16",
        "npm": "^5.5.1",
        "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
    },
```

And configuration in app.module.ts is

```
   import { AuthMethods, AuthProvider, FirebaseUIAuthConfig, FirebaseUIModule, AuthProviderWithCustomConfig } from 'firebaseui-angular';

    import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
    import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
    import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
const facebookCustomConfig: AuthProviderWithCustomConfig = {
  provider: AuthProvider.Facebook,
  customConfig: {
    scopes: [
      'public_profile',
      'email',
      'user_likes',
      'user_friends'
    ],
    customParameters: {
      // Forces password re-entry.
      auth_type: 'reauthenticate'
    }
  }
};

const firebaseUiAuthConfig: FirebaseUIAuthConfig = {
  providers: [
    AuthProvider.Google,
    facebookCustomConfig,
    AuthProvider.Twitter,
    AuthProvider.Github,
    AuthProvider.Password,
    AuthProvider.Phone
  ],
  method: AuthMethods.Popup,

};
@NgModule({

  imports: [
     AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
     AngularFireDatabaseModule,
     AngularFireAuthModule, FirebaseUIModule.forRoot(firebaseUiAuthConfig),
  ],
  providers: [HousesService, BookingService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

[after this settings when i click in login page my app throw following error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhfdT.png)

Comment: post your HTML here

Answer (score 0):

Firebase sdk is at older version, updating it to the latest version should solve the problem